# Rails 3 form_for helper not submitting action correctly

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form:

```
<% @page_title = "Delete Technician: #{@technician.name}" %>  

<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list', :id => @technician.id}, :class => 'back-link') %>  

<div class="technician delete">  
<h2>Delete Technician</h2>  

<%= form_for(:technician, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @technician.id}) do |f| %>

<p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this technician?</p>

<p class="reference-name"><%= @technician.name %></p>

<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= submit_tag("Delete Technician") %>
</div>

<% end %>
</div>
```

when I click on the submit button this is the url that I get:
    www.site.com/technicians/1

instead of
    www.site.com/technicians/destroy/1

am I not using the form_for helper correctly or is it a configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. There is no reason for a form when a link or a button would do. Why not just this

```
<p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this technician</p>
<div> <%= link_to "Delete", technician_path(@technician), :method => :delete %> </div>
```

That's it.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code but its still directing to /technicians/:id instead of /technicians/:action/:id...I went to routes.rb and put  "match 'technicians/:id' => 'technicians#destroy'".  this works but doesn't seem to be an eloquent way of doing it...thanks for your answer though...

Comment: Can I get a better look at your routes.rb file?

Comment: Oh, and if this is a resource, then, you it should take to /technicians/:id/:action and not /technicians/:action/:id, because the idea is that the action brings a representation of the resource.

Comment: Posv1i3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :technicians
  match 'technicians/:id' => 'technicians#destroy'      match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end

Comment: you don't anything past resources :technicians. It should work. And make sure your destroy action in the controller does its job of deleting the resource and redirecting the user back to whatever page you want it to be rerouted to.

Comment: You don't need to do anything...that one line "resources :technicians" does all the work for you. It creates all the routes for you. go to the console and type in rake routes. you'll see all that rails has done for you.

Comment: my destroy method works (if I manually type in /technicians/destroy/:id...but the button doesn't submit the action 'destroy'...it only submits /technician/:id  not /technicians/destroy/:id or even /technicians/:id/destroy